# Constructing groups with a given subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, gap

I have a finite group $H$ and a number $n$ and would like to construct all groups $G$ of order $n$ such that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. (In fact, I would prefer to construct only those which have $H\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ if this is possible—otherwise I'll just filter out the ones that aren't normal subgroups.)

I don't know if this is simple enough to do by hand but if not I have [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/). My motivation is that I'm looking for groups with a particular property but there are too many groups of order $2^k$ to reasonably search through them all.

Edit: I was asked to give an example. I have several groups $H$ of interest; here is $H_1$ in the format generated by GAP's `GapInputPcGroup`:

```
H:=function()
    local g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,r,f,g,rws,x;
    f:=FreeGroup(IsSyllableWordsFamily,8);
    g:=GeneratorsOfGroup(f);
    g1:=g[1];
    g2:=g[2];
    g3:=g[3];
    g4:=g[4];
    g5:=g[5];
    g6:=g[6];
    g7:=g[7];
    g8:=g[8];
    rws:=SingleCollector(f,[ 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ]);
    r:=[
        [2,g8^2],
        [3,g5],
        [4,g5],
    ];
    for x in r do SetPower(rws,x[1],x[2]);od;
    r:=[
        [2,1,g2*g8],
        [3,1,g4],
        [4,1,g5],
        [6,1,g6*g7*g8],
        [7,1,g8],
        [8,1,g8],
        [3,2,g3*g4*g5],
        [4,2,g3],
        [6,2,g7],
        [4,3,g5],
        [6,3,g6^2*g7^2],
        [7,3,g6*g7^2],
        [6,4,g6*g7*g8^2],
        [7,4,g6],
        [6,5,g6*g8],
        [7,5,g7*g8^2],
        [7,6,g8^2],
    ];
    for x in r do SetCommutator(rws,x[1],x[2],x[3]);od;
    return GroupByRwsNC(rws);
end;
H1:=H();
```

$H_1$ (like $H_2$ and $H_3$) has order 1296 and I am interested in $n$ which are small multiples of this order. Its `StructureDescription` is $((((C_3\times C_3) : C_3) : Q_8) : C_3) : C_2$ but this does not uniquely define it—in fact $H_3$ has the same `StructureDescription`.

Comment: It will depend quite a bit on $H$. Also, what do you know about $G/H$? -- As an example, if $H$ has order $2$ and $n=2^{10}$ then GAP will not solve this problem this year.

Comment: It could be that [GrpConst](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/grpconst.html) package may be of some help. Is that always the case that $n$ is a power of 2?

Comment: @JackSchmidt: $n/|H|=|G/H|$ is small, not more than 10. $n$ is a number with lots of groups (else I would just construct all groups of order $n$ and test).

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Not always, but that special case is certainly of interest. Most of the time $n=2^k\cdot m$ with $m$ small.

Comment: @Charles: if $m$ is a prime and $|H|=2^k$, there is a way in GrpConst to construct cyclic extensions of $H$: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grpconst/htm/CHAP005.htm - but in your case $H$ is not necessarily a $p$-group?

Comment: Another idea may be to refine the search using `SmallGroupsInformation` (e.g. call `SmallGroupsInformation(512)` to see how rank and $p$-class depends on the number) and/or some precomputed properties which are listed in the documentation for `AllSmallGroups`, namely `IsAbelian`, `IsNilpotentGroup`, `IsSupersolvableGroup`, `IsSolvableGroup`, `RankPGroup`, `PClassPGroup`, `LGLength`, `FrattinifactorSize` and `FrattinifactorId` (not available for all orders, though - see `AllSmallGroups` manual entry for the exceptions. Perhaps then it may be feasible to test only shortlisted groups?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I believe $H$ is not a $p$-group in any of the interesting cases. Sometimes $m=1$ and thus $G$ is a $p$-group, though.

Comment: Well, perhaps [The Upwards Extension Method](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grpconst/htm/CHAP006.htm) may be used then. Would you mind extending the question describing a couple of interesting cases, please? GAP input to create $H$ would be fine.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: FWIW `UpwardsExtensions` has a bug -- it doesn't expect to be called on large solvable groups. It would be easy to patch, but I just used CyclicExtensions instead, hoping $k$ and $m$ are small.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: thanks - hope GrpConst authors have been notified. The manual says that `UpwardsExtensions` will _usually_ only be used for the determination of non-soluble groups, so I hope the bug does not influence solvable cases at least in the package. @Charles, thank you for the example!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your specific $H_1$ has enough structure that the extensions of $H_1$ by small groups are fairly controlled. Unfortunately moving up from $H$ to $G$ is less well supported than moving from $G/H$ to $H$, but with $H$ so large compared to $G/H$, it makes more sense to start with $H$.

Suppose you wanted $G/H_1$ to be the dihedral group of order 10. The following GAP code does this by realizing that the dihedral group of order 10 has a minimal subnormal subgroup of order 5, and above that a composition factor of order 2.

```
# Get access to "CyclicExtensions"
gap> LoadPackage("GrpConst");;

# convert input to a form CyclicExtensions likes
gap> h := Image( IsomorphismPermGroup( H1 ) );;

# make larger groups K with [K:h] = 5
gap> h5s := CyclicExtensions( h, 5 );;

# make even larger groups G with [G:K]=2, so [G:h] = 10
gap> h52s := Concatenation( List( h5s, x -> CyclicExtensions( x, 2 ) ) );;

# make even larger groups? choose another prime
# gap> h522s := Concatenation( List( h52s, x -> CyclicExtensions( x, 2 ) ) );;

# Fancy code for solvable groups -- removes duplicates
gap> nodupes := List( RandomIsomorphismTest(
> List( h52s, g -> rec(code:=CodePcGroup(g), order:=Order(g) ) ), 7),
> r -> PcGroupCode(r.code, r.order) );;
```

Now we have a list of possible G. We can choose the ones we like however we like, but for instance if we wanted $G/H$ to be dihedral, we might proceed like this:

```
gap> AbelianInvariants( h );
[ 2 ]
gap> List( nodupes, AbelianInvariants );
[ [ 2, 2, 5 ], [ 2, 2 ] ]
gap> hd10 := nodupes[2];; # Where did the 5 come from? Ah, G/H was cyclic not dihedral
# Now find the copy of h in there, notice the weird order
# Also, we only find one injection, but there are two distinct injections
gap> inj:=IsomorphicSubgroups( hd10, h :findall:=false)[1];;
gap> g := hd10;; h := Image(inj,h);; StructureDescription(g/h);
"D10"
```

If you didn't mind $G/H$ being cyclic, then you could do the same idea:

```
gap> hc10 := nodupes[1];;
gap> inj:=IsomorphicSubgroups( hc10, h :findall:=false)[1];;
gap> g := hc10;; h := Image(inj,h);; StructureDescription(g/h);
"C10"
```

As $[G:H]$ gets larger (especially if it has lots of factors), the story of where $G/H$ came from becomes more complicated. Once $[G:H]$ is divisible by 60, you run into other serious problems: $G/H$ may no longer have a composition series with cyclic factors. You are then stuck with the methods that start with $G/H$ and go “down” to $G$ by constructing $H$'s chief series.

Comment: There might be other methods if $H$ is known to be some sort of classical group (it does not look exactly like $\Gamma U_3(2)$, but it is pretty close).

Comment: Thank you. I'm a GAP neophyte -- how would I change the code to use other $G/H$? And does it matter than in your example $|G|=12960$ and so $60|n$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, wrong $n$. 60 is only a problem when it divides $[G:H]$.   -- So the first parts, h5s, h52s, these are constructing groups K with [K:H] = 5, and then for each of those, constructing groups G with [G:K] = 2. So you need to know how to make G/H out of groups of prime order. If [G:H] is too big or too composite, that is a pain. If it is a prime power, then you just keep using CyclicExtensions(...,p) for p that prime. If it is composite, then you don't just need the factorization of $[G:H]$, but also the factorization of $G/H$ (which is the same, but order might matter).

Comment: The "nodupes" line is safe to not understand. You just need to change h52s to whatever list of list of groups you need. It removes isomorphic groups (which are a huge problem if H lacks structure or noise, but for your H it actually kept a third of its answer, which is pretty good).

Comment: I tried to make the code easier to understand. `nodupes` is still safe to run without understanding, but it's less convoluted now.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for all the questions, but can you explain why the `h5s` and `h52s` lines are so different? Why is it not `h5s := Concatenation( List( h, x -> CyclicExtensions( x, 5 ) ) );;` or `h52s := CyclicExtensions( h5s, 2 );;`? Maybe this is obvious but I don't see it.

Comment: @Charles: the output of `h5s` is a list. At the next step `CyclicExtensions` is applied to each element of this list, returning a list. With `Concatenation` we just "glue" all lists together to get a "flat" list and not a list of lists.